# Twitter gem best practice - controller vs. initializer

Tags: ruby-on-rails, twitter-gem

I have a registered app on Twitter and am able to post to my twitter feed.  However, I can only get it to work when I put the initializer in my controller's create action.

```
        client = Twitter::REST::Client.new do |config|
          config.consumer_key = ''
          config.consumer_secret = ''
          config.oauth_token = ''
          config.oauth_token_secret = ''
        end

        client.update("Hello World!")
```

I got to this point by following the advice in this post:
  [Twitter integration rails 4 app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19057123/twitter-integration-rails-4-app)

How do I make this work by having it read a file in my config/initializers / what would the best practice be?

Answer (score 4):

So you have a few options. One is to assign the twitter client to a global variable in an initializer:

```
# config/initializers/twitter.rb
$twitter = Twitter::REST::Client.new do |config|
  # ... 
end
```

Then use the `$twitter` global variable elsewhere. I tend to dislike using global variables as it pollutes the global namespace. My alternative is to define class attributes on the relevant class. You could for example define it on `ApplicationController`, although I'd recommend creating a separate class to handle more complex cases. Using the `ApplicationController` example, this is what it would look like:

```
# app/controllers/application_controller.rb
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  class << self
    attr_accessor :twitter
  end
end

# config/initializers/twitter.rb
ApplicationController.twitter = Twitter::REST::Client.new do |config|
  # ... 
end
```

But again, i'd recommend to have a separate class instead of using application controller, if you are going to use this method.

Comment: Thank you for responding.  I'm slightly confused still.  You didn't like the first or second option you proposed.  Is there a better one, or is it a lesser than two evils solution? Thanks again!

Comment: @brad the first solution will work just fine. Functionally they both are the same, it's just up to preference really.

Answer (score 3):

I would potentially just do the following:

```
# app/controllers/application_controller.rb

def twitter_client

    Twitter::REST::Client.new do |config|
      config.consumer_key        = ENV["TWITTER_CONSUMER_KEY"]
      config.consumer_secret     = ENV["TWITTER_CONSUMER_SECRET"]
      config.access_token        = ENV["TWITTER_ACCESS_TOKEN"]
      config.access_token_secret = ENV["TWITTER_ACCESS_SECRET"]
    end

end
```

Then in any of your other controllers or views you should be able to use the `twitter_client` method.

For example here's a tweet controller where the index action searches for tweets containing "Foo" and takes three of them:

```
# app/controllers/tweets_controller.rb

def index

    @tweets = twitter_client.search("Foo").take(3)

end
```